# Author information from SVN

Tags: svn

In a revision there are more than 200 files (.java). I want to use the SVN blame coommand in order to find out the authors information who has edited those files on that particular revision.
blame command can be used in the following way-
svn blame --xml http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/readme.txt

But the main problem I am facing is - how can I do that recursively for all the files in that particular revision ? What will be the svn command in that particular situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running this on a machine that can use the UNIX program 'find', you could run:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec svn blame --xml {} \;
```

This will put the output for all java files in the terminal. Should you wish to have the information for all files: replace *.java by *.
You might want to save the information to a file by adding something like

```
> authors.xml
```

after the command.

Comment: Thanks @Dekker. Is there any way that I can traverse the svn repository and can use the blame command ?